# Override builtin perspective layout in Eclipse-RCP product

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to override the layout of a built-in perspective  in my Eclipse-RCP product?

In particular, I wish to add a custom view and change the layout of the Debug perspective. I know how to do it with a custom perspective (`IPerspectiveFactory.createInitialLayout()`). I'd want that my custom layout to be permanent -survive the "Reset perspective" command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that implements `IPerspectiveFactory`.

Add a perspectives extension to your `plugin.xml`.  Here's one of mine.

```
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
       <perspective
           class="gov.bop.cobolsupport.perspectives.CobolPerspectiveFactory"
           icon="icons/ispf_editor.gif"
           id="gov.bop.cobolsupport.CobolPerspective"
           name="Cobol"/>     
   </extension>
```

Your users can change your perspective, and save their changes if they wish.  That's built into Eclipse.

However, when you extend your perspective, the Reset Perspective command resets the perspective to how you defined it in your `Perspectivefactory` class.

Comment: But I dont' want to create a new perspective here, I want to modify a builtin one (the Debug perspective).

Comment: You could try modifying the Debug perspective on your Eclipse RCP, giving it a different name when you save it, and see if the new perspective is passed to your RCP product when you build it.  Otherwise, you'll have to create your own perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Extending a perspective is possible by using the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions`.

> Plug-ins can add their own action sets, views, and various shortcuts
>   to existing perspectives by contributing to the
>   org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions extension point.

To extend the default debug perspective paste the following code in your `plugin.xml`:

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
      <perspectiveExtension
            targetID="org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugPerspective">
         <view
               ratio="0.5"
               relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList"
               relationship="right"
               id="com.jens.customdebug.views.SampleView">
         </view>
      </perspectiveExtension>
   </extension>
```

You have to define a relative view (in my case the task view named `org.eclipse.ui.views.TaskList`) and the id of your own view (in my case `com.jens.customdebug.views.SampleView`)

**Source:**

To get further information how to use this extension point, take a look [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_advext_perspectiveExtension.htm).
For the configuration markup of this extension point you may also take a look at [this page.](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_perspectiveExtensions.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. However, this seems to allow to add views to an existing perspective, but not to redefine the default layout, as in `createInitialLayout()`

Comment: Okay, but maybe you are lucky in overriding the class `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugPerspectiveFactory`? You have to add the dependency `org.eclipse.debug.ui` in your plugin.xml in order to have access to this class. (That's the last idea I have)